# I'm disabled, but looking for work

Tags: resume, disability

I've gone over my resume with my former professor and gotten a glowing letter of recommendation from him. However, the first answer I usually get is that my resume only goes until 2014. That is correct, I've been out of work since 2014, but in the meantime, I've kept my skills sharp, and gone back to school. The professor is impressed with my work, the employers, not so much. How do I communicate my disability on my resume without divulging too much personal informaton?

Comment: Could you post a bit about your disability and what your limitations are?  We can definitely help you if you give us a few more details.  I have added the "disability" tag to your post to make it a bit more clear

Comment: When did you start school? How does the gap on your resume look like?

Comment: Is your long unemployment a result of your disability? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Also, is the school you attended from 2014-2018 on your resume now?

Comment: @DavidK not a dupe

Comment: @RichardU So far the question is "How do I communicate my disability on my resume without divulging too much personal informaton?", which is essentially the same question. It's not clear if the unemployment is related to the disability, or if it's simply a long unemployment in addition to a disability. I think the former would be a different question, but that is not clear from how the question is currently written. If the OP clarifies the situation, I would be happy to retract my close vote.

Comment: It's unemployment because of disability. I just a year ago got the meds to make me a normal human being again, and they really help. Here's a link to my resume: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BFInjVDhDnewnUHJ1D5oBq7ykSxW0ibDD2XUi-2Qz90/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So you are not "_disabled but looking for work_" as the title says. Please edit your Q and include info from comments. Your Q is more like how to explain the gap after being disabled

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question right, you have not been employed since 2014, I would explain clearly that you are disabled and what you have done to keep your skills sharp in this time outside of the workforce. I would also include a copy of your professors recommendation.

Regardless of your disability, after doing this small polish to your resume, it will always come down to the amount of applications you submit. It's a numbers game, the more you apply for the higher your odds of success. Best of luck.. T

Answer (score -1):

For the time frame beyond 2014, could you enter something like "Personal Skill Development" and then summarize all of the things that you have done to keep up to date?  If there is a period in which you were in school, you can include that as a separate line and describe what subject material you had.

I think the main point is, remove that blank spot from 2014+.